# How to parse a moment.js date object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am looking to diff the duration in months and days for 2 dates. I having trouble accessing the properties of the object I get back from moment.js.

I can't seem to access the properties of the Duration._data object.

```
var x = moment(); //todays date
var y = moment("2015-12-1"); // an earlier date
var duration = moment.duration(x.diff(y));
console.log("diff: ", duration);
```

returns:

```
diff:  
Duration {_isValid: true, _milliseconds: 106742243043, _days: 0, _months: 0, _data: {…}, …}
_data:
days: 17
hours: 10
milliseconds: 43
minutes: 37
months: 4
seconds: 23
years: 3
```

Was hoping to get the months and days props, using duration._data.days for example. But I get the error message:

Property '_data' does not exist on type 'Duration'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use duration setter like [`months()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/months/), [`days()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/) etc

Here a live sample:

```js
var x = moment(); //todays date
var y = moment("2015-12-1", 'YYYY-M-D'); // an earlier date
var duration = moment.duration(x.diff(y));
console.log("diff: ", duration.months(), duration.days());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to add the [`format()`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#basics) method to duration have a look at [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `range`, Luke:

```
var x = moment(); //todays date
var y = moment("2015-12-1"); // an earlier date
var duration = moment.duration(x.diff(y));
const range = moment.range(y, x);
const days = range.diff('days');
console.log("diff: ", days); // gives the number of days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = moment(); //todays date
var b = moment("2015-12-1"); // an earlier date
var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
b.add(years, 'years');

var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
b.add(months, 'months');

var days = a.diff(b, 'days');

console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days');
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this function to get the the difference in dates.

```
  const availableTime = moment(endDate);
  const timeDifference = availableTime.diff(moment(startDate));
  return moment.duration(timeDifference);
```

You can then:

```
duration.days()
duration.minutes()
```

Etc..